# How to disable everything in android until some task in an app is completed?

Tags: android, android-studio

Sorry for the ambiguous title but I couldn't think of anything better than this.

I am trying to make a quiz app, in which:

when student starts test, he/she might not be able to do anything( back, go to home, recent, see notifications, open another app) until he/she finishes the test.

I had seen such a kiosk-like thing on the web.

There was a kiosk mode mentioned on the android developers documentation but I want to do it without rooting. It must start only when certain activity is started and must stop when some other activity closes.

Comment: Please share the code of what you tried? Which exact difficulties have you faced?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that's not possible for a normal app running on a non-rooted device.

I'd be surprised (and a bit concerned) if it were, since it would allow malicious app developers to lock users out of their devices.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides Android platform to developers to develop app which tune with google intention. Thats why google have Playstore to make Apps trustworthy between developer and users.

Rather than violating Android rules, Why not you try something which will respect Android flow.

Like:

1.Do your implementation based on `Activity/Fragment` Life-cycle method`(OnCreate,OnStart,OnPause,etc)`.

2.Write algorithm(Business logic) such that users can not go out of your current screen otherwise they will loos session, etc.

Lets #BuildForBillions.